# Custom Launcher App for Sony Xperia M2 doesn't work

Tags: android, android-launcher, sony-xperia

We are developing a launcher application where we'll be disabling following other features on the phone other than overriding Home button  :-

1. Back Button
2. Recent Apps
3. Status Bar
4. Power Button

After final development of the app, and it works perfectly fine with other phones like **Karbonn Titanium X** and **Sony Xperia L**.But the app starts behaving very weirdly after installing on **Sony Xperia M2** like below mentioned

- If the phone is locked, then phone never gets unlocked
- Phone starts getting heated quite a few times

Any help to resolve above issues is much appreciated.
If anyone has also faced such issues with other phones also please share your thoughts on it.

If rooting of the phone is needed then please provide the links to root Sony Xperia M2 as it will be my first trial in rooting device :)